# Calculate probabilities for set binomial outcomes provided with probabilities for each event in set? Excel

Tags: excel, probability, binomial-coefficients

The problem is as follows:

Let's say there will be "X" independent events in my binomial tree, and I know the probability of all "X" events being a "1" or a "0" outcome. How can I use excel to calculate the probability of every possible sum total? (addition of all 1s and 0s, ie X, X-1, X-2, ..., 1, 0)

For example I have 4 events in my series (eventually I want up to 17) with probabilities of 0.36, 0.09, 0.91, 0.36.

How do I get excel to spit out:

`P(score=4) = .033`
`P(score=3) = ...`
`P(score=2) = ...`
`P(score=1) = ...`
`P(score=0) = .01`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Binomial tree calculation is iterative process: calculate current state from previous state probabilities.

Let's state `n` has probabilities `Pn(x)` for each `x`, where `x` is `sum total`. Then state `n+1` has probabilities:

```
Pn+1(x) = Pn(x) * (1-p) + Pn(x-1) * p
```

On state `n+1` probability to have sum total `x` is equal to sum of two probabilities:

- probability to have sum total `x` on state `n` multiplied by probability to have **zero** on event: `(1-p)`
- probability to have sum total `x-1` on state `n` multiplied by probability to have **one** on event: `p`

So, you start from state `0`, where `P0(0) = 1` and can expand such tree on any number of events:

[image: binomial tree]

*Look at formula for N6 for clarification*